# How to connect two activities?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, activity-diagram

I'm looking over internet for the solution but I can't find anything.

I have a big system with multiple interfaces.

In our company we have an uml repository where we have an activity diagrams for all use cases.

And here:
I know that I should use actions on activity diagram and I can't connect two activities by control flow.
But
We want to have also reusable actions/activities for interface methods with diagram for the method body.

Is there any possibility to connect two activities by object flow or control flow?

Comment: _an activity diagrams for all use cases_? Jesus, what the heck does that look like? Like Napoleon's battle plan fot Waterloo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't connect two activities by control flow
> Is there any possibility to connect two activities by object flow or control flow?

you want to call an activity from an other, for that just use a call behavior action where the behavior is the called activity.

From §*16.3.4.1 Call Behavior Action* page 454 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) :

> The call of an Activity is indicated by placing a rake-style symbol within the Action symbol (see Figure 16.15, left). The
> rake resembles a miniature hierarchy, indicating that this invocation starts another Activity that represents a further
> decomposition. An alternative notation in the case of an invoked Activity is to show the contents of the invoked Activity
> inside a large round-cornered rectangle symbol (see Figure 16.15, right).

[image]